# Cannot set button image inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, uistackview, swift4, xcode9

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` which has a `UIStackView` that fills the whole cell.

Inside that `UIStackView` I am trying to add `subviews` but I'm running into two problems here.

First one is that I cannot see the `UIStackView` being added to the `cell`, even setting the stack view background color to a different one it doesn't show.

The second problem is that my app - in this case it is a `Today Extension Widget` crashes when I'm instantiating a button image as `button.setImage(:_)`

Here's the code:

```
@objc lazy var composeButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "compose_icon").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCompose), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

let stackview = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [composeButton, reloadButton])
stackview.distribution = .fillEqually
stackview.axis = .horizontal
addSubview(stackview)
stackview.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddinfLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)



extension UIView {
    /// Anchor a specific view to a superview
    @objc func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, paddingTop: CGFloat, paddinfLeft: CGFloat, paddingBottom: CGFloat, paddingRight: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
        }
        if let left = left {
            leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddinfLeft).isActive = true
        }
        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
        }
        if let right = right {
            rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
        }
        if width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }
        if height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        }
    }

    /// Rounds the corners of a UIView object
    /// parameters: corners - the corners to round (upperLeft, upperRight, lowerLeft, lowerRight);
    ///             radiud - the desired cornerRadius to apply to the desired corners
    @objc func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

The app crashes on this line

> button.setImage(image, for: .normal)

It crashes with a `SIGABRT` error as shown in the image bellow.

Does anyone spot the problem here ?

[image: SIGABRT]

Comment: @the4kman I have. In the code above you see that I use `imageLiteral(:_)` but that's because the copy-paste of the source code brings that on, on Xcode I'm accessing directly the image.

Comment: What line of code are you actually using to instantiate the image?

Comment: @DonMag as you can see in the sample code, the image is instantiated in the button declaration-closure. I have even tried to add the image to the button after the button's added to the view but it still crashes. I think this might be an issue with the `Today Extension Widget`, which in this case contains a `UICollectionViewCell` in it.

Comment: @IvanCantarino - right... but you said copy-paste changed the actual code?

Comment: @DonMag if you implement in the Xcode an image and you access that image literal, which appears on your Xcode screen as an image and if you copy it the copied text will show as the imageLiteral(:) seen above because it will not copy the image bitmap itself.

Comment: ok - do you see a difference if you use `let image = UIImage(named: "compose_icon")` ? And do you get an error or do you get valid output if you add `print("image size:", image?.size)` before the `button.setImage` line?

Comment: Before the button.setImage everything worked as expected. I now tried as you said, accessing the UIImage(named:) and the app now doesn’t crash, but the image doesn’t show ! Good thing it doesn’t crash now accessing as you’ve said

Comment: @DonMag somehow I've done an `if-let` statement to check if the image is found, but it is not, even that the name is correct and I've even tried with `png and jpg` extensions on the name.

Comment: ah - you say this is part of a `Today Extension Widget`? Are you sure the image is included in that build target?

Comment: @DonMag I was writing this exact same comment as you've replied. I completely forgot to add the Image to the `Today Extension Bundle` so it could access the image from the Assets folder - omg.
Please , consider writing a formal answer so I can accept it as correct , since you've got it :D

Comment: @IvanCantarino - Done... glad you've got it worked out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is part of a `Today Extension Widget`, make sure you've included the image in that build target.

A future debugging tip: When you see an error that "really shouldn't happen," try thinking about step-by-step. In this case, while the `.setImage` line appeared to be the culprit, if you had checked the validity of your `let image =` line, you might have saved a little time.